# Error in template parse errors in component angular 9

Tags: angular

My doubt is the following one I have two components one of presentation and another container in angular 9, when I try to import the component of presentation in the component container gives me a syntax error I would appreciate your help to solve the problem. Thanks

current-weather.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrentWeatherService } from '../services/current-weather.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-current-weather',
  templateUrl: './current-weather.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./current-weather.component.scss'],
})
export class CurrentWeatherComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public weatherService: CurrentWeatherService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

weather-card.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Weather } from 'src/structures/weather.structure';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-weather-card',
  templateUrl: './weather-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weather-card.component.scss']
})
export class WeatherCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() weather : Weather;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

current-weather.component.html

```
<app-weather-card [weather]="weatherService.weather$ | async as weather" ></app-weather-card>
```

ERROR in Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 'as' at column 33 in [weatherService.weather$ | async as weather] in C:/Projects/projects-angular/weatherapp/src/app/current-weather/current-weather.component.html@0:29 ("]weatherService.weather$ | async as weather" >"): C:/Projects/projects-angular/weatherapp/src/app/current-weather/current-weather.component.html@0:29

Comment: Do you need the 'as weather'?

Comment: Seems like the error is coming  form the template, do pos tcode for that as well.

Comment: Why do you need `as weather`?

Comment: because it is a service that I have with an observable to obtain in the application some data that I obtain from an api, that same syntax had it in the previous component and it worked normal did not have problems

Comment: Thank you I was able to fix it by removing the as weather and it worked. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The `xxx$ | async as xxx` syntax is only supported in the `*ngIf` directive. The error you faced is because you are using it in a component input binding.

You don't need it if you are only making one subscription, but if you really wanted to you'd need to do something like:

```
<app-weather-card *ngIf="weatherService.weather$ | async as weather" [weather]="weather"></app-weather-card>
```

It is referred to in the documentation as "Storing a conditional result in a variable":

> You might want to show a set of properties from the same object. If
> you are waiting for asynchronous data, the object can be undefined. In
> this case, you can use ngIf and store the result of the condition in a
> local variable as shown in the the following example.
>
> This code uses only one `AsyncPipe`, so only one subscription is
> created. The conditional statement stores the result of
> `userStream|async` in the local variable user. You can then bind the
> local user repeatedly.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-a-conditional-result-in-a-variable